# Adding two tokens together (integers). Flex/Bison

Tags: bison

I have a simple Bison file with some simple grammar. I am taking an unending list of expressions, and my goal is to make a single definition for the expression that adds the values of two tokens together.

At line 20, there is a grammar rule that shows what I am trying to achieve. Unfortunately, it does not work. How can I achieve this functionality?

### Bison File

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int yylex();
void yyerror(const char* msg);
%}

%token INT
%token PLUS
%token END


%%
expr_list:    END
          { exit(0); }
        | expr
        | expr expr_list
;

expr:         INT PLUS INT
          { printf("%d\n", ($1 + $3)); }
;

%%


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}


void yyerror(const char* msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! %s\n", msg);
}
```

---

### Flex File

```
%{
#include "adder.tab.h"
%}

%%
(\+)        return PLUS;
[0-9]+      return INT;
(END)       return END;
%%
```

Comment: please copy the file here instead of in an external link. questions should be self-contained

Comment: @phuclv added bison and flex source.

Comment: Can you clarify "does not work"? In what way does it not work? Do you get an error? An unexpected result? Something else? In either case, what's your input, expected output and actual output or error message?

Comment: @sepp2k Everything gets up and running fine. When I type in "END"  the program exits. When I type in `10 + 5`, `0` is printed. This is likely due to a poorly defined grammar rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parser you have this:

```
expr:         INT PLUS INT
          { printf("%d\n", ($1 + $3)); }
```

This takes the semantic values of the two `INT` tokens and adds them, which is fine. If this always produces 0, that means there must be something wrong with the tokens' semantic values. So let's look at the corresponding lexer action:

```
[0-9]+      return INT;
```

Here you never assign anything to `yylval`, so `$1` and `$3` in your parser rule will be unassigned. To assign a meaningful semantic value you can use `strtol` to convert the string in `yytext` to an integer:

```
[0-9]+      yylval = strtol(yytext, NULL, 10); return INT;
```

For proper error handling for numbers outside of `int`'s range, you should check `errno` after calling `strtol`.